# What's the local DNS name for container cluster nodes in a gcloud project?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a gcluod project with a couple of compute instances and a Container Engine cluster. The (unmanaged) compute instances' IP can be resolved using `[instance-name].c.[project-name].internal`. Is there a similar DNS name, like an A record with multiple values, for the GKE nodes?

What we want to do is to access a cluster `NodePort` service from the compute instances. A multi-value DNS record would be fine because it doesn't matter which node we access. Individual GKE node names must be considered ephemeral.

I've tried to use the instance group name, `gke-...` as found using

`gcloud container clusters describe [cluster-name] | grep instanceGroupManagers`
 
but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The GKE nodes, just like the other VMs, can be individually resolved using `[node-name].c.[project-name].internal`. But there isn't a single DNS A record that lists all of the node names together.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Since a listing would be so useful in combination with NodePort I will not accept this answer just yet. There might be workarounds.

Comment: It's a more general problem of how to access a k8s service (nodeport or otherwise) from outside of the cluster. The only mechanism that is currently supported on GCP is to expose the service externally (e.g. outside of your project's private network) but we have heard a few times that it would be great if it were easier to access from other VMs on the same internal network.